# ASP.NET FindControl Of Textbox and Get Value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I added a textbox dynamically as follow:

```
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();

        tb.ID = "Tb1;
        tb.Text = "Tb1";




        Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
```

When I try to retrieve the value, it fails because apparently it can't find it and it's assigned null :

```
                TextBox tb = Page.FindControl("Tb1") as TextBox;
                Label1.Text = tb.Text; //this doesn't work because tb is apparently null
```

Comment: you added it to `Panel1` so go searching for it there.  not on the `Page`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextBox tb = Panel1.FindControl("Tb1") as TextBox;
```

> The FindControl method can be used to access a control whose ID is not available at design time. The method searches only the page's immediate, or top-level, container; it does not recursively search for controls in naming containers contained on the page. To access controls in a subordinate naming container, call the FindControl method of that container.